# fstream function doesn't read or open the file

Tags: c++

i am trying to use fstream for an assignment but i think ifstream doesn't open my file or reads it wrong

My code is supposed read points from a file and give the distance, diameter etc...

when i run the code with "11 4 -3 3" in the file
all my integer x1,x2,y1 and y2 becomes -858993460 and my output is 0.00 for everything
the code works perfectly without fstream when i input with the keyboard on the screen.

I checked with
if(!fin)
cout >> "cannot open"
and it output "cannot open" so i guess it doesn't opens..

here is my code :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

double distance (int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2)
{double distance;
distance = ((x2-x1)*(x2-x1)+(y2-y1)*(y2-y1));
distance = sqrt(distance);
return distance;
}
double radius (int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2)
{double radius;
radius = distance(x1,x2,y1,y2);
return radius;
}
double circumference (double radius, double pi)
{double circumference;
circumference = 2*pi*radius;
return circumference;}

double area (double radius, double pi)
{ double area;
area = pi*radius*radius;
return area;}

int main()
{
ifstream fin;
fin.open("TextFile1.txt");
int x1;
int x2;
int y1;
int y2;
double pi = 3.1416;
double Radius;
double Circumference;
double Area;
double Diameter;

fin >> x1 >> y1 >> x2 >> y2;

Radius = radius(x1,x2,y1,y2);
Circumference = circumference(Radius, pi);
Area = area(Radius,pi);
Diameter = radius(x1,x2,y1,y2)*2;

cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << Radius << endl;
cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << Diameter << endl;
cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << Circumference << endl;
cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << Area;

fin.close();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please only put relevant code into the question and format it.

Comment: Is TextFile1.txt located in the working directory?

Comment: Try using the full path to `TextFile1.txt` in the `fin.open()` call.

Comment: @MichaelBurr i already tried it doesn't work..

Comment: @clcto what do you mean by working directory ? it is in the same folder as my programm

Comment: @MichaelBurr nevermind i forgot to put \\ instead of only one slash.. but i am supposed to give this assignment with the file, so it will no longer be in the same path

Comment: Something simpler to debug first - can you just read the file?:  `string s; while (getline(fin, s)) { cout << s << endl; }`

Comment: How you execute the program will determine what the working directory is. How do you start the program?

Comment: @mathilde: tip - use forward slashes (`/`), It works even on Windows.